# Framework to manage historical data of JPA entities

Tags: java, jpa, database-versioning

About 1 or 2 years ago, I stumbled upon a framework that could manage old revisions of JPA database data. For each managed table TABLE_T, it would create a table TABLE_VERSIONED_T and whenever data in TABLE_T changed, an entry was created in TABLE_VERSIONED_T.

Now I cannot for the life of me remember the framework's name or find it on the web. I browsed some other so questions that dealt with this topic, but none mentions a framework.

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of [Hibernate Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/). At least this enables full history auditing of entities by simply adding an annotation to the entity.

Cheers,